# How to get number of records in a model in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using GenericAPIView and in model serializer to get data from tables. Now I can't understand how can I get the number of records from table in my rest api.

below is my sample code where I am getting records

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
       path('ContactList/<int:user>/',views.ContactList.as_view()),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class ContactList(GenericAPIView, ListModelMixin):
    def get_queryset(self):
       username = self.kwargs['user']
       return Contacts.objects.filter(user=username).order_by('-last_message')
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request , *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contacts
        fields = ['id','user','Contact_id','last_message']
```

in above code I am getting all the contacts of some specific user. now How can I get number of records(contacts) related to this user.

for example if I send user 11 in URL I should get the number of records where user=11

Comment: Do you have pagination enabled on this API?

Comment: Do you mean by `if I send user 11 in URL I should get the number of records where user=11` that you want to retrieve contact by user id ?

Comment: Yes exactly @Rvector. as in above code getting records by user id

Answer (score 0):

if I correctly understand you need to return # of records besides the contacts
you  can override the `list` method and do the following

```py
class ContactList(GenericAPIView, ListModelMixin):
       serializer_class = ContactSerializer
       permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
       def get_queryset(self):
         username = self.kwargs['user']
         return Contacts.objects.filter(user=username).order_by('- 
          last_message')

       def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    
            page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
            if page is not None:
                serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
                return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    
            serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
            count = queryset.count()
            return Response({"count":count, "data":serializer.data})
```

also you can add pagination will solve it

Comment: How to get this from url

Comment: every thing leave it as your setup just add list function to the View class so the final result will be as i my edite answer

Comment: Why this list function is not working alone. I mean if I delete the get function this does not give me the results

Comment: this class inherits GenericAPIView which has  get defined already, hope to copy and past the code in your file and see the result

Answer (score 0):

this is the easiest way to get count of the object. in view write this:

class FiguresAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

```
def get(queryset, request, *args, **kwargs):

    queryset1 = IsoGate.objects.filter(gatestatus=1)
    queryset2 = IsoGate.objects.filter(gatestatus=0)
    
    gate_open = queryset1.count()
    gate_closed = queryset2.count()
    

    return Response(
        {
            "gate_open": gate_open,
            "gate_closed": gate_closed,
        }
    )
```